# Why does this SVG shape work differently on Chrome than Safari?

Tags: html, css, svg

On the fiddle with safari you'll notice it doesn't have the bottom border. If you go visit the fiddle with Chrome, you'll see the bottom border. The hover effect will work on both browsers, but I'm trying to diagnose why the border bottom doesn't work on Safari.

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/XJeqd/

**HTML:**

```
 <body>
    <div class="name">
        <div class="svg-wrapper">
          <svg height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect class="shape" height="60" width="320" />
            <div class="text">STEVE</div>
          </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  background: #303030;
  min-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.name {
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    cursor: default;
}

.svg-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;  
}

.shape {
  stroke-dasharray: 140 540;
  stroke-dashoffset: -474;
  stroke-width: 8px;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #9a5cb4;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  transition: stroke-width 1s, stroke-dashoffset 1s, stroke-dasharray 1s;
}

.text {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  color: #fff;
  top: -48px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.svg-wrapper:hover .shape {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 760;
}
```

Comment: On Safari it just seems to not want to take the border-bottom: 5px solid black; and in Chrome it takes it and inherits the Stroke colour.. I don't get it.

Comment: [Pics or it didn't happen.](http://i.imgur.com/xYZ4clO.jpg)

Comment: You're kidding right? Just go look for yourself at the fiddle. It's linked up in my question right before the code.

Comment: I'm a little kidding. I originally only read the title, so I thought it was a difference in rendering. I can now see the question is specific to `border-bottom`.

Comment: Actually I take it back, I'm not kidding. What are you attempting to display? I can see that the border does not show when applied to `.shape`, but does it look the same if you apply it to the `svg` element in Chrome as it does in Safari?

Comment: I'm just on my phone now about to head to bed so I can't show you pictures until tomorrow. It's supposed to show a bottom border of 5px and then when you hover it does the stroke in a rectangle around the text. The bottom border doesn't display on safari though. The border needs to be applied to the shape because it's apart of the shape being drawn and it changes and morphs when hovered into the stroke and then when not being hovered it's just the bottom border. Hope that makes sense. I'll put up pictures tomorrow if there is no answer by then. Thanks!

Comment: Using Chrome on Windows and viewing the jsfiddle I'm not able to see a black `border-bottom` coming from `.shape`.

Comment: I don't see a border on Chrome or Safari.  `border-bottom` is not a valid display property for SVG `<rect>`s.  I would be very surprised if any browser or SVG renderer supported it.

Comment: Agreed with @BigBadaboom -- I'm honestly surprised you're even getting the text within the `<div>` to show up at all within a SVG.  Either do everything with HTML elements and borders, or do it all with SVG.  SVG elements don't have borders (although the `<svg>` as a whole can).

Comment: With my Mac there is an obvious difference so that's why I was asking. Here is Safari - http://i61.tinypic.com/1zz6ph5.jpg and here is Chrome - http://i61.tinypic.com/2lvdz5d.jpg

And the thing that happens on Chrome is what I want to happen across all browsers. It shows the bottom border but then when you hover it morphs it to the stroke effect.. any idea of how I can accomplish this if this is outside the norm? And why does it work on Chrome for OSX?

Answer (score 0):

The underline and animated stroke effect has nothing to do with the CSS border property.

The effect is all done via CSS animations on the SVG `stroke-dasharray`, `stroke-dashoffset` and `stroke-width` properties.  I'm not even sure why the border-bottom is there.  The stroke does work for me in Safari (5.1.7), but it doesn't animate smoothly as in Chrome.  It just jumps from one state to the other (thick underline to thin box).

Possibly that's because Safari 5 doesn't support CSS animations on those SVG properties.  You should be able to achieve the same effect via either normal SVG (SMIL) animations or using javascript to modify those properties.

I'm not sure why you are not seeing any stroke in your version of Safari.  What version are you using?

Comment: Safari Version 7.0.2

Do you have another fiddle idea that completes what I want to do?